# DBConnectionFactory: error getting dbconnection jdbc/dotCMSPool

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, dotcms

Hello I am facing a strange problem when I am deploying the Dotcms app in a server which runs tomcat 7. Of course I have configured the connection with the database with the correct username, password and url. The log file shows:

```
 12/03/15 12:59:10:107 EET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:                                                                                    
[12/03/15 12:59:10:108 EET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:                                                                                    
[12/03/15 12:59:10:108 EET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:                                                                                    
[12/03/15 12:59:10:108 EET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:            OOOO                            7777777   7777       7777     77777777  
[12/03/15 12:59:10:108 EET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:            OOOO                 OO       777777777  77777      77777    77777777   
[12/03/15 12:59:10:108 EET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:            OOOO                OOO      77777       777777     77777   7777        
[12/03/15 12:59:10:108 EET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:      OOOOOOOOOO   OOOOOOOO   OOOOOOOOO 7777         7777777   777777   7777        
[12/03/15 12:59:10:108 EET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:     OOOO  OOOOO  OOOO  OOOO    OOOO    7777         7777777  7777777    777777     
[12/03/15 12:59:10:108 EET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:    OOOO    OOOO  OOO    OOOO   OOOO    7777         77777777 777 7777     777777   
[12/03/15 12:59:10:108 EET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:    OOOO    OOOO OOOO    OOOO   OOOO    7777         777  777 777 7777        7777  
[12/03/15 12:59:10:108 EET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:    OOOO    OOOO  OOO    OOOO   OOOO    77777        777  777777  7777         7777 
[12/03/15 12:59:10:108 EET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:     OOOO   OOOO  OOOO   OOO    OOOO     77777       777   7777   7777        7777  
[12/03/15 12:59:10:108 EET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:      OOOOOOOOOO   OOOOOOOO      OOOOO    777777777  777   7777   7777  777777777   
[12/03/15 12:59:10:108 EET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:                                                                                    
[12/03/15 12:59:10:108 EET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:                                                          Content Management System 
[12/03/15 12:59:10:108 EET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:                                                                                    
[12/03/15 12:59:10:108 EET]  INFO util.AsciiArt:                                                                                    
[12/03/15 12:59:11:117 EET]  INFO server.CMISServiceFactoryImpl: Initializing in-memory repository...
[12/03/15 12:59:11:129 EET]  INFO server.CMISServiceFactoryImpl: ...initialized in-memory repository.
[12/03/15 12:59:11:129 EET]  INFO impl.CmisRepositoryContextListener: Initialized Services Factory: com.dotcms.enterprise.cmis.server.CMISServiceFactoryImpl
[12/03/15 12:59:11:140 EET]  INFO util.SystemProperties: Loading file:/home/koutroum/public_html/WEB-INF/classes/system.properties
[12/03/15 12:59:11:140 EET]  INFO util.SystemProperties: Loading file:/home/koutroum/public_html/WEB-INF/classes/system-ext.properties
[12/03/15 12:59:11:147 EET]  INFO util.PropsLoader: Loading file:/home/koutroum/public_html/WEB-INF/classes/portal.properties
[12/03/15 12:59:11:147 EET]  INFO util.PropsLoader: Loading file:/home/koutroum/public_html/WEB-INF/classes/portal-ext.properties
[12/03/15 12:59:11:270 EET]  INFO business.CacheLocator: loading cache administrator: com.dotmarketing.business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl
[12/03/15 12:59:11:277 EET] ERROR db.DbConnectionFactory: ---------- DBConnectionFactory: error getting dbconnection jdbc/dotCMSPool
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/dotCMSPool] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:820)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:158)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at com.liferay.util.JNDIUtil.lookup(JNDIUtil.java:88)
    at com.dotmarketing.db.DbConnectionFactory.getDataSource(DbConnectionFactory.java:41)
    at com.dotmarketing.db.DbConnectionFactory.getConnection(DbConnectionFactory.java:85)
    at com.dotmarketing.db.DbConnectionFactory.getDBType(DbConnectionFactory.java:257)
    at com.dotmarketing.db.DbConnectionFactory.isMsSql(DbConnectionFactory.java:345)
    at com.dotcms.journal.business.ESDistributedJournalFactoryImpl.<init>(ESDistributedJournalFactoryImpl.java:45)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.FactoryIndex.create(FactoryLocator.java:295)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.FactoryLocator.createService(FactoryLocator.java:237)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.FactoryLocator.createService(FactoryLocator.java:69)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.Locator.getServiceInstance(Locator.java:41)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.FactoryLocator.getInstance(FactoryLocator.java:227)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.FactoryLocator.getDistributedJournalFactory(FactoryLocator.java:112)
    at com.dotmarketing.common.business.journal.DistributedJournalAPIImpl.<init>(DistributedJournalAPIImpl.java:28)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.APIIndex.create(APILocator.java:436)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.APILocator.createService(APILocator.java:352)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.APILocator.createService(APILocator.java:101)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.Locator.getServiceInstance(Locator.java:41)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.APILocator.getInstance(APILocator.java:340)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.APILocator.getDistributedJournalAPI(APILocator.java:219)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl.<init>(DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl.java:121)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:379)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.CacheLocator.init(CacheLocator.java:120)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.CacheLocator.getInstance(CacheLocator.java:268)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.CacheLocator.getContentletCache(CacheLocator.java:146)
    at com.dotcms.content.elasticsearch.business.ESContentFactoryImpl.<init>(ESContentFactoryImpl.java:82)
    at com.dotcms.content.elasticsearch.business.ESContentletAPIImpl.<init>(ESContentletAPIImpl.java:166)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.APIIndex.create(APILocator.java:424)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.APILocator.createService(APILocator.java:352)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.APILocator.createService(APILocator.java:101)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.Locator.getServiceInstance(Locator.java:41)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.APILocator.getInstance(APILocator.java:340)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.APILocator.getContentletAPIImpl(APILocator.java:160)
    at com.dotmarketing.portlets.contentlet.business.ContentletAPIInterceptor.<init>(ContentletAPIInterceptor.java:47)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.APIIndex.create(APILocator.java:425)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.APILocator.createService(APILocator.java:352)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.APILocator.createService(APILocator.java:101)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.Locator.getServiceInstance(Locator.java:41)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.APILocator.getInstance(APILocator.java:340)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.APILocator.getContentletAPI(APILocator.java:169)
    at com.dotmarketing.cms.urlmap.filters.URLMapFilter.init(URLMapFilter.java:336)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4775)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5452)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1256)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:219)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:611)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[12/03/15 12:59:11:277 EET] ERROR db.DbConnectionFactory: ---------- DBConnectionFactory: error : com.dotmarketing.exception.DotRuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/dotCMSPool] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
[12/03/15 12:59:11:277 EET] FATAL business.CacheLocator: Unable to load Cache Admin:com.dotmarketing.business.DotGuavaCacheAdministratorImpl
[12/03/15 12:59:11:288 EET] ERROR db.DbConnectionFactory: ---------- DBConnectionFactory: error getting dbconnection jdbc/dotCMSPool
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/dotCMSPool] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:820)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:158)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at com.liferay.util.JNDIUtil.lookup(JNDIUtil.java:88)
    at com.dotmarketing.db.DbConnectionFactory.getDataSource(DbConnectionFactory.java:41)
    at com.dotmarketing.db.DbConnectionFactory.getConnection(DbConnectionFactory.java:85)
    at com.dotmarketing.db.DbConnectionFactory.getDBType(DbConnectionFactory.java:257)
    at com.dotmarketing.db.DbConnectionFactory.isMySql(DbConnectionFactory.java:351)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.PermissionBitFactoryImpl.<init>(PermissionBitFactoryImpl.java:117)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.FactoryIndex.create(FactoryLocator.java:288)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.FactoryLocator.createService(FactoryLocator.java:237)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.FactoryLocator.createService(FactoryLocator.java:69)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.Locator.getServiceInstance(Locator.java:41)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.FactoryLocator.getInstance(FactoryLocator.java:227)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.FactoryLocator.getPermissionFactory(FactoryLocator.java:84)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.APIIndex.create(APILocator.java:419)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.APILocator.createService(APILocator.java:352)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.APILocator.createService(APILocator.java:101)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.Locator.getServiceInstance(Locator.java:41)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.APILocator.getInstance(APILocator.java:340)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.APILocator.getPermissionAPI(APILocator.java:116)
    at com.dotcms.content.elasticsearch.business.ESContentletAPIImpl.<init>(ESContentletAPIImpl.java:167)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.APIIndex.create(APILocator.java:424)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.APILocator.createService(APILocator.java:352)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.APILocator.createService(APILocator.java:101)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.Locator.getServiceInstance(Locator.java:41)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.APILocator.getInstance(APILocator.java:340)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.APILocator.getContentletAPIImpl(APILocator.java:160)
    at com.dotmarketing.portlets.contentlet.business.ContentletAPIInterceptor.<init>(ContentletAPIInterceptor.java:47)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.APIIndex.create(APILocator.java:425)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.APILocator.createService(APILocator.java:352)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.APILocator.createService(APILocator.java:101)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.Locator.getServiceInstance(Locator.java:41)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.APILocator.getInstance(APILocator.java:340)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.APILocator.getContentletAPI(APILocator.java:169)
    at com.dotmarketing.cms.urlmap.filters.URLMapFilter.init(URLMapFilter.java:336)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4775)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5452)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1256)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:219)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:611)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[12/03/15 12:59:11:288 EET] ERROR db.DbConnectionFactory: ---------- DBConnectionFactory: error : com.dotmarketing.exception.DotRuntimeException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/dotCMSPool] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
[12/03/15 12:59:11:303 EET] ERROR db.DbConnectionFactory: ---------- DBConnectionFactory: error getting dbconnection jdbc/dotCMSPool
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/dotCMSPool] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:820)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:158)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at com.liferay.util.JNDIUtil.lookup(JNDIUtil.java:88)
    at com.dotmarketing.db.DbConnectionFactory.getDataSource(DbConnectionFactory.java:41)
    at com.dotmarketing.db.DbConnectionFactory.getConnection(DbConnectionFactory.java:85)
    at com.dotmarketing.db.DbConnectionFactory.getDBType(DbConnectionFactory.java:257)
    at com.dotmarketing.db.DbConnectionFactory.isMySql(DbConnectionFactory.java:351)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.PermissionBitFactoryImpl.<init>(PermissionBitFactoryImpl.java:117)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.FactoryIndex.create(FactoryLocator.java:288)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.FactoryLocator.createService(FactoryLocator.java:237)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.FactoryLocator.createService(FactoryLocator.java:69)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.Locator.getServiceInstance(Locator.java:41)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.FactoryLocator.getInstance(FactoryLocator.java:227)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.FactoryLocator.getPermissionFactory(FactoryLocator.java:84)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.APIIndex.create(APILocator.java:419)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.APILocator.createService(APILocator.java:352)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.APILocator.createService(APILocator.java:101)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.Locator.getServiceInstance(Locator.java:41)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.APILocator.getInstance(APILocator.java:340)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.APILocator.getPermissionAPI(APILocator.java:116)
    at com.dotmarketing.portlets.files.business.FileAPIImpl.<init>(FileAPIImpl.java:64)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.APIIndex.create(APILocator.java:445)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.APILocator.createService(APILocator.java:352)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.APILocator.createService(APILocator.java:101)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.Locator.getServiceInstance(Locator.java:41)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.APILocator.getInstance(APILocator.java:340)
    at com.dotmarketing.business.APILocator.getFileAPI(APILocator.java:247)
    at com.dotmarketing.filters.CMSFilter.init(CMSFilter.java:574)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4775)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5452)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1256)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:219)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:611)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the correct pool name bound to the correct context.  You might need a /META-INF/context.xml file in the root of your web app that does this and looks something like:

https://github.com/dotCMS/core/blob/master-3.2/extra/tomcat/context.xml